# Combinando e rotacionando dois patches no matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Estou tentando simular um teste feito com feijões no matplotlib, e para isso estou usando duas elipses combinadas, como na figura:

[image: Feijao]

```
feijao = Ellipse(xy=(2,2), width=2.5, height = 2, angle = 120)
feijao2 = Ellipse(xy=(2,2.6), width=2.5, height = 2, angle = 75)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'aspect': 'equal'})

ax.add_artist(feijao)
feijao.set_facecolor('#a38d65')
ax.add_artist(feijao2)
feijao2.set_facecolor('#a38d65')

    
ax.set_xlim(0,10)
ax.set_ylim(0,10)

plt.show()
```

Porém eu preciso que o plot contenha mais de um feijão, e que eles variem levemente de angulação. Eu tentei utilizar a própria construção das elipses para isso, mas como cada elipse vai rotacionar em torno do seu próprio eixo, não funciona com todos os feijões.

[image: Conjunto de feijoes]

```
ang=np.random.rand(10)

eli = [Ellipse(xy=(2+(5*i), 2+(7*j)),
                   width=2.5, height=2,
                   angle = ang[i]*360)
       for i in range(10) for j in range (5)]
eli2 = [Ellipse(xy=(2+(5*i), 2.6+(7*j)),
                   width=2.5, height=2,
                   angle = ang[i]*360-45)
       for i in range(10) for j in range(5)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'aspect': 'equal'})

for e in eli:
    ax.add_artist(e)
    e.set_facecolor('#a38d65')
for e in eli2:
    ax.add_artist(e)
    e.set_facecolor('#a38d65')

ax.set_xlim(0, 50)
ax.set_ylim(0, 35)


plt.show()
```

Procurei na documentação e não encontrei, mas teria alguma forma de "combinar" as duas elipses que formam o feijão, e depois replicar esta formação, rotacionando as figuras?

Comment: Um comentário um pouco tangencial, mas particularmente eu tentaria fazer isso em um programa de edição de figuras como o Inkscape, e não diretamente via Python/matplotlib. Você poderia inclusive exportar a segunda figura como um arquivo SVG, abri-la no Inkscape e ajustar da forma que ficar melhor. Falo isso porque já perdi muito tempo tentando ajustar coisas extremamente específicas nas figuras do matplotlib (eixos, cores, proporções, fontes, ...), apenas pra me dar conta de que é mais simples fazer os "toques finais" editando a figura diretamente com um programa mais adequado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode fazer-se isso criando uma PatchCollection, copiando isso e aplicando rotacao e translacao a cada copia:

Por exemplo:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection # acrescentei isto
import matplotlib as mpl
import copy # importar o copy para copiar PatchCollection()

ang=np.random.rand(10)

eli = [Ellipse(xy=(2+(5*i), 2+(7*j)),
                   width=2.5, height=2,
                   angle = ang[i]*360,
                   edgecolor="black")
       for i in range(10) for j in range (5)]
eli2 = [Ellipse(xy=(2+(5*i), 2.6+(7*j)),
                   width=2.5, height=2,
                   angle = ang[i]*360-45,
                    edgecolor="black")
       for i in range(10) for j in range(5)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'aspect': 'equal'})

e1 = eli[0] #Isto e' apenas criar uma forma qualquer para exemplo
e2 = eli2[0]

p = PatchCollection([e1,e2]) # juntar duas elipses

pcopy = copy.copy(p) # criar uma copia

# aplicar uma transformacao com rotacao e translacao a copia
tr = mpl.transforms.Affine2D().rotate_deg(-45).translate(20,20) + ax.transData
pcopy.set_transform(tr)

ax.add_collection(p)
ax.add_collection(pcopy)

ax.set_xlim(0, 50)
ax.set_ylim(0, 35)

plt.show()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: (falta de acentos por causa de teclado ingles)